# PHP Reading Files and Additions

Tags: php, html

I have question with PHP. So I am making a form where you submit your name and it looks at the file and tells you are registered.

```
$file = "Website.txt";
$filehandle = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($filehandle)) {
    $data = fgets($filehandle);
    $str = explode(",", $data);
    for ($i = 0;$i = 2;$i++) {
        echo $str[$i];
        if ($str[$i] == "Kyle") {
            echo "You are registared!";
        } else {
            echo "You are not registared!";
        }
    }
}
fclose($filehandle);
```

When I run the code it is not working. Please help!

Comment: You can use PHP_Beautifier to beautify your code. Aslo how do verify that its not working?

Comment: You mean to use `$i <= 2` or `$i < 2`... `for ($i = 0; $i <= 2;$i++)`  Otherwise your look is never run because `$i = 2` is immediately false.

Comment: have you considered using a simple database like `SQLlite` , `MySQL` or `MongoDB` Instead of flat file

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski o, `$i = 2` is always `true`: The return value of an assignment is always the value itself. Kyle should see an infinite loop, right Kyle? However, it's right, that it should be `<=`.

Comment: Thank you for the notice for the for loop. I verify not working that the screen shows HTTP 5000 I think it was.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `for` loop. Second part is an assignment not a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it's hard to tell if this is looking correctly at your file, but if I were you I'd simplify the code by doing this:

```
$file = "Website.txt";
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$array = explode(",",$data);
foreach ($array as $item) {
  if ($item == "Kyle") {
    echo "You're registered!";
  }
}
```

NOTE: code not tested yet.

I'd also recommend using a regular expression or at least stripping the whitespace from the item you're comparing, like this:

```
if (preg_match("/needle/",$haystack)) {
}

//or 

if (trim($haystack) == "needle") {
}
```